# If IE functions

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Unfortunately, I haven't found any answer to my question in the web.
How to make a user with IE see another html page (not index.html)?

Comment: Do it server-side please provide your server-side language. You can always check browser with the useragent.

Comment: Are the pages dynamically created, or static?

Comment: agree with @micha, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` or `get_browser` could handle this.

Answer (score 10):

You could use conditional tags together with meta redirect.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/ie.html">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: and because it redirects to a ie specific document instead of to a different website...

Comment: @CodyGray I was the first to upvote this answer, because the other one initially contained spelling mistakes. *aside* Quoting the OP "Because my web-site is on pure css3". Instead of redirecting to a new page, the OP should link to another stylesheet, for IE-browsers: `<!--[IF IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->`. To exclude a stylesheet for IE, use: `<!--[IF !IE]--><link rel="stylesheet" href="non-ie.css" type="text/css" /><!--[endif]-->`. See also [MSDN: conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

If you are running apache you could do this server-side through a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MSIE.*
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ ie.html [L]
```

The above will redirect clients using any flavor of IE to `ie.html` and all others to `index.html`

Answer (score 3):

try thi code,

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: @micha: OP is not mention any serverside language. may be he just using simple html files.

Comment: then why downvoting me? he just answer my deleted comment. i said he was copied from me and he said he just googled it. so it it a point to downvote my answer. i'm the first one who answer this question. is that the reason to downvote?

Comment: @micha I tried to Google, but I didn't find anything helpful. Maybe that's because I didn't know exactly what to search

Comment: @micha What did you type in search field?

Comment: @PavelShimansky - I understand that it may be difficult when you don't know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @micha - Yes, assuming he knows what a redirect is in the first place. If you look at the original question he doesn't use the word `redirect`, try googling for `user with IE see another html page` - how many good hits do you get?

Comment: @micha - Oh, sorry I didn't know you were a `pro googler`, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't advise redirecting different browsers to different pages - it makes maintaining your page a lot harder.

As mentioned in the comments, you should do this server side (if you really have to). Doing it client side is in general bad design, as you'll force your visitors to load and wait for two pages (the redirecting page as well as the final page being shown).

In case you're trying to do one of those "IE is bad bad bad, you won't see anything here unless you use browser X" pages, then just let me tell you that you'll most likely scare away more possible visitors than people you "convince" to use a different browser. Also consider in this case that IE made huge improvements over the last revisions making special markups or considerations almost unnecessary, if you're keeping your code standards conform.

If you'd like to use browser specific markup code (like not yet standardized stuff such as some of the gradient and shadowing code), just add them all to the same page, browsers will ignore the entries with different vendor prefixes.

Comment: The website is created for my friends from college. They all have Chrome, Opera, Mozilla or Safari. So, I don't really care about loosing some visitors =)

Comment: Why even worrying about redirecting at all?

Comment: Because my web-site is on pure css3

Comment: @PavelShimansky Instead of redirecting to another page, you'd better **include a different stylesheet** for specific IE versions, through conditional comments (see top upvoted answers).

Comment: @RobW Does IE support transitions?

Comment: @RobW IE10, but not 9, 8, 7 or earlier =)

Comment: @PavelShimansky Correct. The site I linked to is quite handy as a quick reference for such features. Have you already looked at my other comment at the top upoted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Do it with jQuery. I made it if you go to index.html and the user is browsing via internet explorer I redirect him to the download page of mozilla. Simply replace the alert through a redirect and it will be fine !

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
  alert( $.browser.version );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the meta redirect tags to automatically redirect the visits to index.html page to another page.

Anyway, it is better to control this with in the webserver side configuration.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "/ie.html"
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Better to use `<meta>` redirects incase they have javascript disabled.